# what does it mean "public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');" in CakePHP

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am new to the subject. I can't realize what does it

```
public $helpers = array('Html','Form'); //var helpers
```

mean. please anyone help me.

Comment: Please read the http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html

Comment: omg,That is basic thing.Why dont try to get training on php.https://allphptips.wordpress.com/category/tutorials/cake-php/

Comment: In cakephp, there have The Helpers to support you do something. When you want to call one of the helper you just use $helpers = array('Html') but if you want to call more than 1 you will add next of old one and separate by the comma. It will be like $helpers = array('Html','Form'); This means you call 2 helpers named Html and Form in CakePHP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic part of the CakePHP manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **FormHelper** does most of the heavy lifting in form creation. The **FormHelper** focuses on creating forms quickly, in a way that will streamline validation, re-population and layout. The **FormHelper** is also flexible - it will do almost everything for you using conventions, or you can use specific methods to get only what you need.[see documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)